# Associatedtype depends on protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, associated-types

I struggle with `associatedtype` to make it work as I want. So ask for clarification and explanation why example below doesn't work. Bellow example is executable in [playground](http://online.swiftplayground.run/).

I have this structures `Foo` and `Bar` where both implement `DocumentTemplate`.

```
public protocol DocumentTemplate {
}

public struct Foo: DocumentTemplate {
    public var _id: String!
}

public struct Bar: DocumentTemplate {
    public var _name: String!
}
```

I have generic protocol `DocumentCollectable` require type `T` inherit from `DocumentTemplate`, and two implementations of `UniversalCollectable` depends on `DocumentTemplate` and `FooCollectable` depends on `Foo`.

```
public protocol DocumentCollectable {
    //type T must implement protocol DocumentTemplate
    //error workaround remove ': DocumentTemplate'
    associatedtype T: DocumentTemplate 

    func collect(_ d: T)
}

public class UniversalCollectable: DocumentCollectable {
    public typealias T = DocumentTemplate //error

    public func collect(_ d: T) {
        print("universal done")
    }
}

public class FooCollectable: DocumentCollectable {
    public typealias T = Foo

    public func collect(_ d: T) {
        print("foo done")
    }
}
```

When I execute this:

```
let u = UniversalCollectable()
u.collect(Foo())
u.collect(Bar())

let f = FooCollectable()
f.collect(Foo())
```

I'll get error message

```
error: type 'UniversalCollectable' does not conform to protocol 'DocumentCollectable'
```

But if I make change to `associatedtype T` not inherit from `DocumentTemplate`, then everything run smooth. But I need type `T` to inherit from `DocumentTemplate`.

Comment: A `typealias` must be a concrete type, not a protocol. In this case `T` is not a generic.

Comment: [Protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/5133585), so you can't use `DocumentTemplate` as the type for `T` in `UniversalCollectable`.

Comment: But when I remove `: DocumentTemplate` from associatedtype then I'm available to use protocol in typealias. Or I missing something oblivious?

Comment: Read the answer I linked. What you are trying to do (`typealias T = DocumentTemplate`) is "unsound" in general.